# How to program a Dreamweaver-style IDE, integrated with language engines?

Tags: java, c++, ide

**Premise:**
I started writing an IDE web application a year or so ago. It would be similar to Adobe's Dreamweaver. It would have a WYSIWYG, text editor, and debugging tools. Of course, there are other new features that I'd like to write- otherwise, I wouldn't be writing my own IDE. I wrote a syntax highlighter and parser in JavaScript and started writing the WYSIWYG using the HTML DOM. However, as fast as rendering and JavaScript engines have gotten, they aren't the best choice for writing an IDE. So, yes, I realize how difficult an IDE is to program.

**Question:** Currently, I plan to write the IDE in Java or C++ (preferably Java). Instead of writing my own interpreter for PHP/HTML/CSS/JavaScript/etc., I'd like to integrate my application with as many existing tools as I can. I know Java has Rhino and Quercus. Gecko and pretty much any JavaScript engine can be integrated with C++. My question is:

1. What are the best engines available for C++ and Java? For PHP, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript specifically.
2. Would it be possible to tap into these engines to write a debugger and other tools? Preferably, as unobtrusively as possible, so I can update engine versions without much hassle.

I'm not sure what the best way to approach this. I'd prefer not to have to go back and rewrite the whole thing because my design is flawed. Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: "If you can imagine an _entire book_ that answers your question, you’re asking too much."—[faq].

Comment: Come on. I bet there's less than eight good engines for C++ and Java.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with an open source IDE and extend it.  Netbeans and Eclipse already support a good number of languages and have debuggers.

IntelliJ CE supports all the languages mentioned, so perhaps you only need to extend it to do what you want.  You might not need to write any code at all. ;)